# Android: Resume specific instance of activity

Tags: android, resume

In my Android app I have a list of opened instances of the same activity (This activity basically contains a `WebView`.) When the user clicks on an item in the list, I want to resume the according activity showing the correct website. However, using an intent with flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` or `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` will not do the trick since the Activity is the same (just different instances with different extras).

I think I have to use multiple (e.g., 10) identical Activities with different names. Each website is then launched in its own Activity. However, when I want to open more than 10 websites, I run into troubles again.

Any other ideas how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem you can rely on [Android Tasks](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html).

What you have to do:

Launch WebView Activities using flags: `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK`

Inside these activities call `getTaskId()` and make the ID available to your main activity. When you want to resume an activity, do the following:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
am.moveTaskToFront(taskId, 0);
```

Requires permission `permission android.Manifest.permission.REORDER_TASKS`

When you want to return to your main task from a WebView task (which consists of a single Activity), do this:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
String packageName = context.getPackageName();
Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
context.startActivity(launchIntent);
```